# Does HTC Sync work well with Thunderbird?

Tags: sync, htc-sync-3.0

As I no longer have access to Outlook, I have to look for alternatives for managing mail, agenda's and contacts.

My first guess would be Thunderbird, but I wonder how well this syncs with HTC Sync as I never had any trouble setting it up with Outlook, I would prefer that it stayed that way.

So does anyone have any experience with syncing their Android phone through Thunderbird?

Comment: Any reason you can't sync to Google and use Thunderbird as an IMAP client?

Comment: I can, but it's just that I prefer managing all these things on my desktop and Google's contact management sucks. So normally I used Outlook as an email client for all my email addresses and managing everything from one application. But I do have everything syncing with Google off course ;-)

Comment: Well, with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/7307/ and http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/ you should be able to manage your contacts and calendar in Thunderbird and sync with Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend, rather, using Thunderbird as an IMAP client with the Google Contacts and Lightning add-ons ( http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/7307 and http://mozilla.org/projects/calendar). You should be able to manage your contacts and calendar in Thunderbird and sync with Google. So then your Thunderbird and phone will each synchronize to and from Google.